# Why is my WebSocket automatically closing using Flask?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, websocket

I've set up a very basic websocket server using flask.

**websocket.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_uwsgi_websocket import GeventWebSocket
app = Flask(__name__)
ws = GeventWebSocket(app)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
@ws.route('/foobar')
def echo(wscon):
    msg = wscon.receive()
    if msg is not None:
        wscon.send(msg)
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(gevent=1000, host='0.0.0.0', port=9090)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="Javascript">
            var s = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.3.49:9090/foobar");
            s.onopen = function() {
                alert("connected !!!");
                s.send("js send to server");
            };
            s.onmessage = function(e) {
                alert("recv message")
                var bb = document.getElementById('blackboard')
                var html = bb.innerHTML;
                bb.innerHTML = html + '<br/>' + e.data;
            };

            s.onerror = function(e) {
                alert('error');
                alert(e);
            }

            s.onclose = function(e) {
                alert("connection closed");
            }

            function invia() {
                var value = document.getElementById('testo').value;
                alert(value);
                s.send(value);
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>WebSocket</h1>
        <input type="text" id="testo"/>
        <input type="button" value="invia" onClick="invia();"/>
        <div id="blackboard" style="width:640px;height:480px;background-color:black;color:white;border: solid 2px red;overflow:auto">
        </div>
    </body>
```

when I access http://ip:9090, I get the blow information:

> connected !!!
>
> recv message
>
> connection closed

why websocket auto close? And occasionally there will be an error

> [uwsgi-http key: 192.168.3.49:9090 client_addr: 192.168.3.1
>   client_port: 9177] hr_instance_read(): Connection reset by peer
>   [plugins/http/http.c line 646]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Seems like your are trying for echo gevent server. [Example code](https://github.com/zeekay/flask-uwsgi-websocket/blob/master/examples/echo-gevent/echo.py)**

You need to keep the connection running by a loop. Change as following:

```
@ws.route('/foobar')
def echo(ws):
    while True:
        msg = ws.receive()
        print(msg)
        if msg is not None:
            ws.send(msg)
        else:
            return
```